# C++ member of class updated outside class

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a question about pointers and references in C++. I am a programmer who normally programs in C# and PHP.

I have two classes (for now) which are the following. 
The X/Y in Controller are continuously changing but i want them up to date in the Commands. I have multiple commands like Forward, Turn, Backward etc.

When i make the commands i give them the controller but the state (X, Y) of the controller are updating every second.

How can i fix that the controller attribute in the Commands are getting updated also every second?

```
class Forward : ICommand
{
    Controller ctrl;

    void Execute() {
        int CurrentX = ctrl.X;
        int CurrentY = ctrl.Y;
        //Check here for the current location and calculate where he has to go. 
    }
}

class Controller 
{
    int X; 
    int Y; 

    void ExecuteCommand(ICommand command) {
        command.Execute();
    }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
Controller controller;

Forward cmd1 = new Forward(1, controller);
Turn cmd2 = new Turn(90, controller);
Forward cmd3 = new Forward(2, controller);

controller.Execute(cmd1);
controller.Execute(cmd2);
controller.Execute(cmd3);
```

I have read something about pointers and references and i think i have to use this but don't know how to use it in this situation.

(code can have some syntax errors but that's because i typed over. Everything is working further except for the updating).

Comment: There is no need for the `new`, you can just allocate that with `Forward cmd1(1, controller);`. Otherwise you would need to have a `delete` and use pointers like `Forward *cmd1 = new Forward(1, controller);`. — Then your `Forward` has a *copy* of `controller`, therefore all changes to not propagate back to `controller` in `main`. You need to have `Controller &ctrl` in `Forward`, then you can update the variables of your `controller` in `main`.

Comment: ... and be careful with the constructor signature (which you haven't shown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use references rather than copy objects you can see changes.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ICommand
{
public:
    virtual ~ICommand() = default;
    virtual void Execute() = 0;
};

class Controller
{
public:
    int X = 0;
    int Y = 0;

    void ExecuteCommand(ICommand & command) {
        //                       ^-------
        command.Execute();
    }
};//,--- semicolons required

class Forward : public ICommand //note public
{
    const int step;
    Controller ctrlCopy;
    Controller & ctrlReference;

public:
    Forward(int step, Controller & ctrl) :
        step(step),
        ctrlCopy(ctrl),      //this is a copy of an object
        ctrlReference(ctrl)  //this is a reference to an object
    {

    }

    void Execute() {
        std::cout << "copy: " << ctrlCopy.X << ", " << ctrlCopy.Y << '\n';
        std::cout << " ref: " << ctrlReference.X << ", " << ctrlReference.Y << '\n';
        //Check here for the current location and calculate where he has to go. 
        ctrlCopy.X += 10;
        ctrlReference.X += 10;
    }
};//<--- semicolons required


int main() {
    Controller controller;

    Forward cmd1(1, controller);
    //Turn cmd2(90, controller); //Left for the OP to do
    Forward cmd3(2, controller);

    controller.ExecuteCommand(cmd1);
    //controller.ExecuteCommand(cmd2);
    controller.ExecuteCommand(cmd3);

    //Do it again to show the copy and reference difference
    std::cout << "Once more, with feeling\n";
    controller.ExecuteCommand(cmd1);
    controller.ExecuteCommand(cmd3);
}
```

Giving

```
copy: 0, 0
 ref: 0, 0
copy: 0, 0  // [1]
 ref: 10, 0 // [2]
Once more, with feeling
copy: 10, 0
 ref: 20, 0
copy: 10, 0
 ref: 30, 0
```

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) shows that the *copy* has X and Y of 0, while the reference shown in [2] has moved by the stated step (in `controller.ExecuteCommand(cmd3)`)

Note, we don't need to use `new` to make this work (don't forget `delete` if you use new).

Also, `void ExecuteCommand(ICommand command)` now takes a reference instead otherwise the by-value copy does "slicing" (e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing))